# Passing IConfiguration to base controller

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

In this project I'm working on I have to create a controller using a base controller and the constructor of the base controller takes IConfiguration (I didn't create this base controller and have no control over the design). When I pass the IConfiguration parameter from the sub class constructor to the base class constructor, the base controller always complained about missing settings in the configuration although I've verified that they were there. The code looks like this:

```
    startup.cs:
    public class Startup {
    ......
       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
       public IWebHostEnvironment WebHostEnvironment { get; }

       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment 
       webHostEnvironment) {
        Configuration = configuration;
        WebHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }

       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
       }

    ........
    }


  launchsettings.json:
  .....

  "profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/v1/Test",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "local"
  }
},
.....

appsettings.local.json:
 ....
 "sec1": {
 "sec2": {
  "key": "local-keyyyyyyyy-hexadecimal",
  ......
        } 
}
```

...

```
public class TestController : myBaseController
{
  private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
  public TestController(IConfiguration configuration,IOtherSerive iotherservice) : 
        base(configuration) {

        Configuration = configuration;
       ......
    }
  ......
 }
```

The base controller looks like this:

```
  .....
  public class myBaseController : ControllerBase 
 {

    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    public string key = string.Empty;

    public myBaseController(IConfiguration configuration) {
        key = configuration["sec1:sec2:key"];<----always complained about missing value from configuration here
       ........
    }
}
```

I wonder what's causing this problem? Thanks in advance!

p.s. The base controller is .net core 2.2 and the controller that inherited from the base controller is .net 3.1.

Comment: According to your description and codes, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I could get the configuration from the appsetting.json file. [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm8ON.png). Could you please post all the settings for appsetting.json or appsetting.development.json and the program.cs codes? I guess you may used the wrong format in the appsetting.json or used a special appsetting.json file setting in the program.cs.

Comment: I am using the same concept and it working fine for me in my project, based on 3.1. Looks like you have an issue in appSettings.json.

Comment: Thanks all! Turns out to be a misspelled setting in appsettings json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I comment says, for this kind of issue, we could firstly check the appsetting.json is format is right or not and check you have used a special appsetting.json file setting in the program.cs.